# EJB multiple FK not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, jpa

I am trying to link entities from one table to two others with foriegn keys. My Tables are:

user -> id(pk), username, password, gender(fk), age(fk)

gender -> id(pk), gender

agegroup -> id(pk), group

all ids are int(11) and all other columns are varchar

user has columns gender & age which holds the integer which is the primary key of the respective tables. All tables are InnoDB & I have linked them up through phpmyadmin using the relation view (found that out here). Looking at the database through the JPA view in Eclipse they are correctly annotated with FK.

I generate the entities from the menu and set up so that my User entity has ManyToOne relations set up for both the fields which is what I want. I have a Users bean class that I create from my servlet adding a user as a parameter to the request and accessed in a jsp file to write values to a page. I want to print the users name their age group and their gender to a page.

```
${user.getUsername()}
${user.getGenderBean().getGender()}
${user.getAgegroup().getGroup()}
```

when I have all three set up in JPA I only get the username printed on the page. Strangely if I re-do the Entities and do not set up the agegroup the gender does get printed. This is not true the other way around. The order above is the how they are used. GenderBean was generated once when I accidentally created bidirectional relation but the name sticks even when I generate the way I want it i.e. unidirectional.

I am using Eclipse Kepler, Glassfish 4, MySql 5.5.31 & eclipselink

I get a sql syntax error with the following:

```
SELECT ID, RANGE FROM agegroup WHERE (ID = ?)
```

I changed groupt to range just in case keyword confusion was happening. Is the fact the ID and RANGE are uppercase anything to do with it as they are not named that way. I have created all my column names lower case.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If case was an issue, I assume you have other fields that wouldn't match up in User and Gender though, so it shouldn't just affect AgeGroup.  Both Group and Range are key words in MySQL, so you might try something else, and watch the logs for exceptions - turn EclipseLink logging and watch for exceptions.  If that doesn't help, more information is required to help you determine what is going on such as the code for the entities and errors in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Chris it was the use of group/range that caused my issue.